# Showig in QTreeWidgetItems data retrieved at runtime

Tags: c++, qt, runtime, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I want to show in a QTreeWidget, hierarchically, some data extracted from a DB.
I thought that a way to do this is converting the data to show in `QTreeWidgetItem`s.

But in that way, i have to create the objects (`QTreeWidgetItem`s) in runtime. And this is the problem. I don't know how to do it.

How can I do this? Or is there a better way to show it?

Example of what I want:
[image: example]

**EDIT:**

The data that will be retrieved and shown hierarchically is:
Universities, areas, carreers and the total amount of each one.

**EDIT 2:**

For if you need i will add more information:

```
QTreeWidgetItem *itm = new QTreeWidgetItem(ui->treeWidget);
itm->setText(0, "University 1");
QTreeWidgetItem *itm2 = new QTreeWidgetItem(itm);
itm2->setText(0,"Area 1 ");

QTreeWidgetItem * itm3 = new QTreeWidgetItem(itm2);
itm3->setText(0,"Lawyer");

QTreeWidgetItem *itm4 = new QTreeWidgetItem(ui->treeWidget);
itm4->setText(0, "University 2");

QTreeWidgetItem *itm5 = new QTreeWidgetItem(itm4);
itm5->setText(0, "Area 2");

QTreeWidgetItem *itm6 = new QTreeWidgetItem(itm5);
itm6->setText(0, "Systems engineering");
```

The code above is like i want but hardcoded. I need to do this with dynamic information retrieved from a DB. I can carry the records to memory, this is not the problem. The problem is how to show this records in differents QTreeWidgetItem, given that the number of "objects" (records of the DB) can be more or less in different time.

**EDIT3 - SOLVED:**

I think that I have to create dynamically the objects.
I don't know that I can do some like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        QTreeWidgetItem *item   = new QTreeWidgetItem(ui->treeWidget);
        item->setText(0, QString::number(i));
}
```

---

Comment: I think you need to make your question more specific, including what have you tried, with code.

Comment: @perencia I've just add more information (EDIT 2). In other words i need to create dynamics objects with the information retrieved. For example if I have in a moment three records I want to show them in three different QTreeWidgetItem. So I have to create the objects dinamically (i think, i don't know if there is a better way) and i can't find how to do that.